# Problema com o pdfMake?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

Estou usando a biblioteca do pdfMake para geração de boletos, e estava funcionando bem, até que fui seguir alguns exemplos da documentação no [site](http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted) e me retornou um erro, busquei a solução em várias issues abertas no GitHub e em outros sites mas nenhum me ajudou, lembrando que estou fazendo a geração dos PDF's no meu servidor NodeJS.

```
/* O método abaixo é outro jeito de conseguir gerar o documento, e 
   esse método achei nos exemplos no site do pdfMake, e esse método 
   funciona, porém não consigo atribuir as funções de 'download()',
   'open' e 'print()'*/
 pdfMake = printer.createPdfKitDocument(conteudoPDF); //Método funcional

    /* O código abaixo é o exemplo que está na documentação e que está
       retornando o erro "TypeError: pdfMake.createPdf is not a function" */
    pdfMake.createPdf(conteudoPDF).open(); // Método não funcional

    pdfMake.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('../pdfs/testeJson.pdf'));
    pdfMake.end();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente usar `pdfMake.createPdfKitDocument(conteudoPDF).open();` e verifica se acontece algum erro!

Comment: Infelizmente retorna o mesmo erro, eu fui olhar na documentação e no GitHub do desenvolvedor que criou o pdfMake e ele não dá commit em nenhum projeto dele do gitHub desde o dia 18 de maio do ano passado, ou seja, ele abandonou a biblioteca e ainda deixou disponível para uso e com bugs, porém ela é muito fácil de usar e realmente cria pdfs através daquele outro método que mostrei no meu trecho de código, mas não tem as opções de imprimir, abrir e fazer download, vou abrir uma nova pergunta para ver se tem como fazer essas 3 opções manualmente, sem uso de bibliotecas, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Tem uma alternativa legal também que é o jsPDF, porém ele apenas salva a página em pdf. Você pode utilizá-lo através do CDN: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js"></script> , para usar para instanciar o objeto jsPDF. Segue a documentação no github: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

Comment: Já pesquisei sobre ele, realmente é uma ferramenta interessante, porém estou pegando dados do MongoDB e colocando direto no PDF, creio que nesse caso ela não atenderia a minha necessidade. Agradeço mais uma vez a sua disponibilidade em ajudar, vlw msm.

Answer (score 0):

```
const PdfPrinter = require('pdfmake');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = class HelloPdf {

    async generatePdf(body, res) {

        var fonts = {
            Roboto: {
                normal: 'app/assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
                bold: 'app/assets/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf',
                italics: 'app/assets/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
                bolditalics: 'app/assets/fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf'
            }
        };

        var printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);

        const title = `${body.title}\n`;

        const documentDefinition = {
            content: [
                { text: title, fontSize: 15, alignment: 'center', bold: true },
            ]
        };

        var pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(documentDefinition);
        const pdfName = 'basic.pdf';

        pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(pdfName))
            .on('finish', function () {
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
                res.download(pdfName, pdfName, (err) => { });
            });

        pdfDoc.end();
    }
}
```

Você pode verificar exemplos de uso na documentação: https://gist.github.com/w33ble/38c5e0220d491148de1c